# Pattern Capture not working for forward slash

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have one of the fields in a record like this:

```
{ 
  ....

  "test_field": "/xyz/abc-2021abs/drf/2021ABC"

  ....
}
```

I am creating a analyzer to not ignore the forward slashes (`/`) with help of [pattern_capture](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html).

Here is my mapping and analyzer for the same.

```
{
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "test_field": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "test_field_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "exact": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "test_field_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer" : "pattern",
            "filter" : [ "test_filter"]
          }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "test_filter" : {
               "type" : "pattern_capture",
               "preserve_original" : true,
               "patterns" : ["(\\p{Punct}+\\p{Alnum})"]
            }
         }
      }
    }
  }
```

When I am checking the tokens generated, the forward slashes (`/`) are ignored and pattern capture does not seem to be working similar to example on [pattern_capture](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html).

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about those java-like `\\p` patterns but this

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "test_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "test_field_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "exact": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "test_field_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "test_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "test_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": false,
          "patterns": [
            "(/[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will tokenize the test field into

```
["/xyz", "/abc-2021abs", "/drf", "/2021ABC"]
```

if that's what you're after...

**EDIT**

There's an even simpler way of achieving this using a custom pattern **tokenizer** instead of a `pattern_capture` **filter**:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "test_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "test_field_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "exact": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "test_field_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_pattern_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_pattern_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "(/[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)",
          "group": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Since you're dealing with paths, you may find the [path hierarchy tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) useful too:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "test_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "test_field_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "exact": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "test_field_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "path_hierarchy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will produce

```
["/xyz", "/xyz/abc-2021abs", "/xyz/abc-2021abs/drf", "/xyz/abc-2021abs/drf/2021ABC"]
```

Comment: I got the tokens that I was expecting for from the first one.
For java-like `\\p` patterns, [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html) says: The pattern capture token filter uses [Java Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Why `"tokenizer": "keyword"` worked instead of `"tokenizer": "pattern_capture"`?

Comment: I got the gist of the `\\p` patterns but I'm not overly familiar with them -- that's why I chose standard regex. As to why `pattern_capture` didn't work -- `(\\p{Punct}+\\p{Alnum})` would've only matched 1 character, not multiple in the group. Check my answer EDIT for one more simplification.